# is this value object

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design

one article has messages. So I have dilemma in terms how should I construct `Message` object. As entity or value object having ddd approach in mind.

`Message` should not be ever tracked independent, without `Article` object. As far as I know value object have no identity, and knowing that how can I track article messages?

If my poco is

```
public class Article {
   public int id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public Message Message {get; set;}
}

public class Message{
   public string body {get; set;}
}
```

should I add Article inside Message to establish tracking of article message. If I add Article to Message class do I break Value object definition?

Update:
my goal is to allow visitors to leave message(s) to specific article. Message should not be tracked independently but should be tracked trough article object.

Comment: Please post complete and correct code. Would it hurt to add the `class {}` ?

Comment: Could you also give more description of what the code is for? You'll get better answers if you describe the situation.

Comment: 'value object' is not a standard term and almost a contradiction. Be clear about what you mean.

Comment: If you are making the `Message` a separate entity it makes sense for it to have a separate ID value as well (`MessageID`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have dilemma in terms how should I construct Message object

At the very least it should be:

```
public class Message
{
   public int Id {get; set;}             // MessageId
   public Article Article { get; set; }  // Owner
   public string body {get; set;}
}
```

depending on your framework, you may want to add/manage the foreign key property as well. EF will understand:

```
public class Message
{
   public int Id {get; set;}             // MessageId

   // use the 'virtual' keyword and/or add an ArticleId and/or use some Attributes.  
   public int ArticleId { get; set; }
   public virtual Article Article { get; set; }  // Owner
   public string body {get; set;}
}
```